# jQuery, function called without parameters, but there is parameters

Tags: jquery, parameters

One thing i can't understand about jQuery, maybe someone can explain me this.

for example:
HTML:

```
<div>
<img class="class1" src="file.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
<img class="class2" src="file.jpg" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.class1, .class2').myfunction();
    });

    function myfunction(param1, param2) {
        var img = $('img', param1);
    }

})(jQuery);
```

So the question is what exactly in param1 and in param2, if function has been called like that(without passing parameters to the function)?

Comment: You can always `console.log(arguments)` in a function body to see the parameters being passed.

Comment: you executed a function that doesn't exist. `myFunction` is not a property of `$.fn`

Comment: Even if you did define `myfunction` properly, there would be no params **because you didn't pass any!**

Comment: Thank you Kevin B, now i understand where is my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call should be as follows:

View:

```
<div>
    <img id="img1" src="file.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
    <img id="img2" src="file.jpg" />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var path1 = $('#img1').attr('src');
        var path2 = $('#img2').attr('src');
        myfunction(path1, path2);
    });

    function myfunction(param1, param2) {
        // your code
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. Or `$.fn.myfunction = function(){myfunction($('div'),'param2')}` then my example will be right too. But thanks.